# Why do consecutive numbers in a JSON tree cause a failed conversion to NSDictionary?

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary

I've been working with Firebase, and in a part of my JSON tree, I had a bunch of consecutive numbers as keys.

Here's an abbreviated portion of that part of the tree:

```
 "matches" : {
      "1" : {
        "0931-Red" : [
            "John Smith"
        ],
        "2022-Blue" : [
            "Paul Adams"
        ]
      },
      "2" : {
        "1489-Red" : [
            "Matthew Brown"
        ],
        "1565-Blue" : [
            "Ian Fowler"
        ]
      },
      "3" : {
        "1652-Red" : [
            ""
        ],
        "2626-Blue" : [
            ""
        ]
      }
}
```

When I downloaded it from Firebase and used this:

```
if let r = ref {
    r.child(accessKey).child("matches").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let groups = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
```

The conversion to NSDictionary failed.

However, when I edited `"matches"` to look like this:

```
 "matches" : {
      "1" : {
        "0931-Red" : [
            "John Smith"
        ],
        "2022-Blue" : [
            "Paul Adams"
        ]
      },
      "2" : {
        "1489-Red" : [
            "Matthew Brown"
        ],
        "1565-Blue" : [
            "Ian Fowler"
        ]
      },
      "4" : {
        "1652-Red" : [
            ""
        ],
        "2626-Blue" : [
            ""
        ]
      }
}
```

*It worked.*

I was able to convert the data to an `NSDictionary`.

This also worked by changing the first `"1"` to `"01"` and appending a string to the beginning of each number like `"match-1"`, `"match-2"`, etc.

Even though my code works, the error is still bothering me because I don't know why it was wrong in the first place.

**Why didn't it work with consecutive numbers as keys in the first place?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From JSONSerialization documentation: "All dictionary keys are instances of NSString." Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization I guess that FireBase at some point use `NSJSONSerialization` and mix Int & String (could be worth a check on their code)